# Deleting virtual field in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, spatialite, virtual-field

I'm trying to delete a virtual field from a layer attribute table. The layer source is a Spatialite database so I know that it's not straightforward to remove permanent fields, but as I understand it virtual fields are stored in the project file, not the database.
I followed the answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147398/qgis-how-to-delete-virtual-fields), but when I try to edit the attribute table the 'Delete field' button remains greyed out:

[image]

UPDATE: I've now discovered that the above happens if the layer is added using `Layer->Add Layer->Add Vector Layer`, but not if using `...->Add Spatialite Layer`, in which case a virtual field CAN be deleted using the appropriate button. I'm a relative beginner, and I hadn't realised it was possible to add Spatialite layers in 2 different ways.
However I'm still not clear if this is a bug, or actually correct behaviour, as I don't understand the difference between the two methods of adding layers (though this is probably a separate question).

Comment: I can confirm that's a behaviour in 2.18.10 - I guess it's because you're using a spatialite database as your input source because it seems to work fine for shapefiles. One solution that works for me is to remove the dataset from the TOC, save the project, and then re-add the dataset. This does away with the virtual field. Might be worth logging a bug ticket as I'm guessing its deactivating the delete column because its a spatialite table, without realising its looking at a virtual field?

Comment: I just did a test with QGIS 2.18.12,
erasing a virtual field (spatial database) works, the icon is activated.

Comment: @Ed Rollason - I tried your workaround (by saving layer style, removing layer in Layer Panel, saving project, re-adding layer and re-applying layer style) and it removed all the virtual fields, as you say. Handy to know (and thanks), though obviously it would be preferable to remove specific fields rather than all of them.

Comment: Can you show the formulas used for the virtual fields? If the `Households` field is referenced in the `Restricted Households` field, you have to delete that first.

Comment: @AndreJ - I'd already deleted them both, as my comment above lol:) But I've recreated a single field `Restricted Households` with expression:  `CASE
 WHEN  "delivery_point:access"  IN ( 'restricted' , 'timed' ) THEN
 CASE
  WHEN  "building:flats"  <> NULL THEN "building:flats"
  WHEN  "building" = 'house' THEN 1
 END
 ELSE 0
END`  Even with this single virtual field the 'Delete field' button is unavailable

Comment: Sorry, should have been `"building:flats" IS NOT NULL` not `"building:flats" <> NULL`, but doubt that's relevant

Comment: I've updated the question with new information, which partially answers the question

Answer (score 2):

I just did a test with QGIS 2.18.12, erasing a virtual field (spatial database) works, the icon is activated

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am also using 2.18.12 (on Windows 10 64bit). The layer source database file is `dbname='D:/Rick/Documents/Maps/QGIS projects/WR 2017-18 transition/OSM_WR.osm.db' table="OSM_WR_polygons" (geometry) sql=`, does this make a difference?

Comment: probably linked to the path, avoids spaces and special characters.

Comment: So is it a bug, or is it a requirement to avoid such characters in pathnames?

Comment: Works for me even with blanks in folder paths.

Comment: just for completeness sake, you can delete using the properties part but if you are thinking you can delete from the attribute table part it does not work